# is it important to install bootstrap 3 with bootstrap 4 in angular project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am creating a new project in angular and I need to install bootstrap in my project. To add bootstrap in my project, I am following this [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap) page.

Either I should follow steps for bootstrap 3 and 4 or just 4. Please guide

Here are steps that i am following.

**Using SASS**

Getting Started
Create a new project and navigate into the project

```
ng new my-app --style=scss
cd my-app
```

Installing Bootstrap

## version 3.x

```
npm install bootstrap-sass --save
```

## version 4.x

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

Configuring Project
Create an empty file _variables.scss in src/.

If you are using bootstrap-sass, add the following to _variables.scss:

```
$icon-font-path: '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
```

In styles.scss add the following:

// version 3

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap';
```

// version 4

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Testing Project
Open app.component.html and add the following markup:

Test Button
With the application configured, run ng serve to run your application in develop mode. In your browser navigate to the application localhost:4200. Verify the bootstrap styled button appears. To ensure your variables are used open _variables.scss and add the following:

// version 3

```
$brand-primary: red;
```

// version 4

```
$primary: red;
```

Return the browser to see the font color changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO!**

Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 3 are totally incompatible with each other!

Bootstrap 4 is almost a complete rewrite of Bootstrap 3.

NEVER mix the two together!

So, when working with Bootstrap you have to decide which of the two versions you wanna use Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4. You must pick either the one OR the other.

They are about as different from each other as a truck is different from a sports car. Both have wheels but that's where the similarities end.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I have used bootstrap 3 and 4 both, but when it comes to build process in aws code build, it failed due to usage of two versions. And it is not a good practice even though you can build the Angular app in production.